# Spring Cloud Gateway YML routing - is there a way to check permissions?

Tags: java, spring-security, routes, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have some microservices, and a Gateway using Spring Cloud. I'm trying to set up the routing in the Gateway. Ideally, I would like to set up the routing in the YML file, or with a RouteLocator bean.

But currently, in my Gateway, I have REST endpoints for every route, which is just sending the request onwards using a WebClient.

(Prior to this, I have a ReactiveAuthenticationManager filter which validates a JWT token. It returns a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken which includes some user authorities it gets from the token).

Here's an example where I have set up a route to a microservice called the tracking service:

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/tracking-service/tracking")
public class TrackingController {

  @Autowired
  private TrackingService trackingService;

  @GetMapping
  public Flux getAllTracking() {
    return trackingService.getAllTracking();
  }

}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class TrackingService {

  private WebClient webClient;

  @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('MANAGER')")
  public Flux getAllTracking() {
    //Make HTTP call to the tracking service
  }

}
```

The reason I have done it this way is because of the @PreAuthorize annotation. If the client's JWT token does not include the 'MANAGER' token, then this will return a 403 forbidden status. Not all of the endpoints require the MANAGER authority and some of the endpoints require other authorities.

My question - is it possible to do this when routing with the YML? I was hoping to see something that looks like this, but I'm not sure it is possible? I have read the Spring docs and looked at all the available filters, and there was nothing that does this job that I could see.

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: tracking
          uri: http://tracking-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/tracking-service/**
          filters:
            - StripPrefix=1
            - PreAuthorize=hasAuthority('MANAGER')
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not in yaml. You can do it with spring security java configuration.

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway and authorization are two separation of concern. Ideally authorization should not be mixed in gateway application. For permission you can directly map it to service like this.

```
@RestController
public class ResourceREST {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/resource/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     @PreAuthorize("@customPermissionEvaluator.hasPrivilege(authentication,'somepermission')")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<?>> user() {
        return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok(new Message("Access allowed")));
    }
}
```

And define custom permission evaluator

```
@Service
public class CustomPermissionEvaluator {

    public boolean hasPrivilege(Authentication auth, String permission) {
        String requiredPermissionCheck = permission.toLowerCase();
        for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuth : auth.getAuthorities()) {
            if (grantedAuth.getAuthority().contains(requiredPermissionCheck)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

As such gateway does not provide any authorization in the routing which is ideal.